# Remote debugging in eclipse issue

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

```
echo "LSE Parser v1.0"
javac -d ../build -classpath ../build:${MY_CLASSPATH} *.java
cd ../build 
jar -cf ../lib/lse.jar .
cd ../src
```

The above is my build script for a java application. there is a serperate run file which has all the CLASSPATH defined and runs the application.

I am trying to remote debug the application on eclipse but facing issues. The code is sitting on unix server host. i've closely followed instructions about debug configurations... for eclipse.

This is what I'm doing:

1. I locate my build (above) in putty terminal and execute with . ./build
2. I type `java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9999`
3. On eclipse **debug config...** I enter a random name, project is lse, gave correct host and gave port number as 9999. checked termination of remote VM. When I click debug, it does not stop on the breakpoint.

NOTE: in the project "lse" are 3 .java source that the application uses. the "lse" project has only src content, however in the Unix host it has all the lib, scripts, config folder.

Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. after step 2, I managed to get 
`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999`

then after step 3, I get some messages on putty

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.
....
```

and see on eclipse a terminated status on debug mode.  java hotspot server  [host bla bla]

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you solved this by now...but looks like you forgot to provide the name of the class for java to run.  If your *main* method was in a source file like *foo/Bar.java*, then you would need to add *foo.Bar* to your java line.  Something like:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9999 foo.Bar
```

You might also consider adding *-g* to your *javac* to generate debug info.

You could avoid all (or most) of this pain if your source was in the IDE that you're trying to debug with...